# how to combine jquery snippets into one

Tags: jquery

When i try to put these all into one, they break. How can they combined into one fluid line of code?

1st snippet -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
setTimeout(function() {
      $('li[data-val="mgc_727"]').trigger('click');
   }, 10);
});
</script>
```

2nd snippet -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('li:contains("clear")').addClass('hide');


});


</script>
```

3rd snippet

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   $(document).on('click', '.mgi_txt_under', function() {
     
       var $wrap = $(this).parents('.mg_box');
       var $inner = $wrap.find('.mg_box_inner');
       if($inner.is('a')) {
           window.location.href = $inner.attr('href'); 
       }
   });
});
</script>
```

I tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('li[data-val="mgc_727"]').trigger('click');
    }, 10);
    $('li:contains("clear")').addClass('hide');
    $(document).on('click', '.mgi_txt_under', function() {
        var $wrap = $(this).parents('.mg_box');
        var $inner = $wrap.find('.mg_box_inner');
        if ($inner.is('a')) {
            window.location.href = $inner.attr('href');
        }
    });
});
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Show the combined code that doesn't work.

Comment: You should be able to take the bodies of each `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {...})` and just put them sequentially inside one of those.

Comment: You probably just misplaced a brace when you were merging them.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
setTimeout(function() {
      $('li[data-val="mgc_727"]').trigger('click');
   }, 10);

$('li:contains("clear")').addClass('hide');

 $(document).on('click', '.mgi_txt_under', function() {

       var $wrap = $(this).parents('.mg_box');
       var $inner = $wrap.find('.mg_box_inner');
       if($inner.is('a')) {
           window.location.href = $inner.attr('href'); 
         }
      });
     });
    });
   });
</script>

Comment: Put it in the question so it's readable.

Comment: You have too many `});` at the end. Couldn't you tell that they didn't match `(` and `{`?

Answer (score 0):

You may just need to use one `jQuery(document).ready(function($){})` to avoid conflicts.

So in your case, you can do :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

// from the 1st snippet
setTimeout(function() {
      $('li[data-val="mgc_727"]').trigger('click');
   }, 10);
 
 // from the 2nd snippet
 $('li:contains("clear")').addClass('hide');

 //from the 3rd snippet
 $(document).on('click', '.mgi_txt_under', function() {
     
       var $wrap = $(this).parents('.mg_box');
       var $inner = $wrap.find('.mg_box_inner');
       if($inner.is('a')) {
           window.location.href = $inner.attr('href'); 
       }
   });

});
</script>
```